# imap_body worked incorrect?

Tags: php, email, imap

`imap_body` didn't work incorrect for me, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The error message comes with text:

> "--0000000000007f934b0574cac3e4 Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset="UTF-8"
>   cxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
>   --0000000000007f934b0574cac3e4 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
>   cxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
>   --0000000000007f934b0574cac3e4-- "

But it should be only

> "cxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

My code is:

```
function display_message($auth_user, $accountid, $messageid, $fullheaders) {
$buttons = array();
$buttons[0] = 'reply';
$buttons[1] = 'reply-all';
$buttons[2] = 'forward';
$buttons[3] = 'delete';
$buttons[4] = 'show-headers';

$message = retrieve_message($auth_user, $accountid, $messageid, $fullheaders);
if(count($message)==0) {
    echo "cannot retrieve message number $messageid".'.<br />';
} else {
    $imap =open_mailbox($auth_user, $accountid); ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> Subject: </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b> <?php echo iconv_mime_decode($message['subject']);?> </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> From: </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b> <?php echo iconv_mime_decode($message['fromaddress']);?> </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> To: </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b> <?php echo iconv_mime_decode($message['toaddress']);?> </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>
                <b> Received: </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b> <?php echo iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", strftime($message['date'])); ?> </b>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php display_toolbar($buttons, "&messageid=$messageid"); ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo iconv_mime_decode($message['fullheaders']); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $message['body']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

}

The `retrieve_message` function is:

```
function retrieve_message($auth_user, $accountid, $messageid, $fullheaders) {
$message = array();
if(!($auth_user && $messageid && $accountid)) {
    var_dump(1);
    return false;
}

$imap = open_mailbox($auth_user, $accountid);
if(!$imap) {
    return false;
}

$header = imap_header($imap, $messageid);

if(!$header) {
    return false;
}

$message['body'] = imap_body($imap, $messageid));

if(!$message['body']) {
    $message['body'] = "[This message has no body]\n\n\n\n\n\n";
}

if($fullheaders) {
    $message['fullheaders'] = imap_fetchheader($imap, $messageid);
} else {
    $message['fullheaders'] = '';
}

$message['subject'] = $header->subject;
$message['fromaddress'] =   $header->fromaddress;
$message['toaddress'] =   $header->toaddress;
$message['date'] =   $header->date;

// note we can get more detailed information by using from and to
// rather than fromaddress and toaddress, but these are easier

imap_close($imap);
return $message;
}
```

Comment: This looks correct as the e-mail message has two different versions varying on the content type (`text/html` / `text/plain`). Both can be different too, have different text depending upon the context.

Comment: Ok, How can i get only "cxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" in message, whithout everything else?

Comment: Thanks, i find solution for me , need to change "$message['body'] = imap_body($imap, $messageid);" on "$message['body'] = imap_fetchbody($imap,$messageid, 1);" in function retrieve_message

Comment: But i have trouble with incoming messages in russian language.
"0JXQn9Ci0JANCg=="